# How to set DropDownChoice selected at particular index/choicedata in apache wicket?

Tags: wicket, dropdownchoice

Hi I have created DropDownChoice component of apache wicket. now what I want to do is that after component creation I want to set some choice as a default selected based on certain condition. I am not getting it anyhow. Anyone can plz help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to select multiple options then you should use `org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.ListMultipleChoice#ListMultipleChoice(java.lang.String, org.apache.wicket.model.IModel<? extends java.util.Collection<T>>, org.apache.wicket.model.IModel<? extends java.util.List<? extends T>>)`. The first model holds the selections, and the second holds all possible options.